# Passing data to a component from ModalController.create()

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Is there a way that I can pass this itemId parameter so that the MarketPlaceItemPage can use that data?

```
async presentMarketplaceItem(itemId: number) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: MarketplaceItemPage,
      cssClass: '',
      mode: 'ios',
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

I'm just not finding what I need in the Ionic documentation.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found something that works from this website https://www.freakyjolly.com/ionic-modal-popovers-pass-receive-data/

```
async presentMarketplaceItem(itemId: number) {
    const modal = await this.modalController.create({
      component: MarketplaceItemPage,
      componentProps:{
        id: itemId
      },
      cssClass: '',
      mode: 'ios',
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

[Here is the official documentation from Ionic](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal#properties)

The property you are looking for is **componentProps**.
Ionic controllers are not listed in their v5 documentation but their were listed under v4.

Another way (faster IMO) is to directly browse sources (ctrl+click), it will show you the controller method signature.